# What is the common-mode range vs the differential-mode range of a differential probe?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

A differential probe has a **differential-mode range** of 5000 Vrms and a **common-mode range** of 2500 Vrms for its input voltage.

What does that mean, and what are the differences between common-mode vs differential-mode, especially in a differential probe, and what should I consider while measuring in order to not break the probe?

Answer (score 1):

Differential mode assumes that the signal in either input are, typically, 180 degrees out of phase (obviously, differential output amplifiers cannot do that for any arbitrary frequency, but you get the idea).

At the peak +/-Voutp of either single ended signal, your probe will sense 2Voutp, as your differential voltage is simply Voutp-(-Voutp).

The common mode voltage, on the other hand, assumes that both voltage signals are in phase. It is a voltage that is **common** to both probe inputs. It doesn't matter if it's a DC or an AC signal, it's a signal that will drive both probe inputs up or down equally (but you'll not see it in your test equipment because your differential probe is subtracting this signal).

Whatever common-signal there is, the probe in question, according to what you stated, can only tolerate that these variations are 2.5kVrms or 3.5kVp. AFAIK, the common-mode range of these probes are bipolar, so this last number applies not only to positive, but negative voltages as well, with respect to 0V.

Answer (score 0):

The **differential-mode** range of a probe defines the maximum voltage difference **between + and - inputs** of the probe.
The **common-mode range** of a probe defines the maximum voltage difference **between +/- and ground** of the probe.